# Каким образом(кодом) записать в С# данное условие?

Tags: c#, массивы, консоль

Превратить массив таким образом, чтобы сначала располагались все
элементы, равные нулю, а затем – все остальные.

Comment: Если вопрос решен, вы можете выбрать наиболее полезный на ваш взгляд ответ ниже и принять его, для этого надо поставить галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 5):

Ваш вопрос немного нарушает правила сайта (учебные задания допустимы только в случае, когда приводится своя попытка решения).

Поэтому я схитрю: я тоже не напишу кода!

Наивная реализация: заводим второй массив, в него кладём нулевые элементы из первого,  а потом кладём все оставльные из первого.

Если нельзя заводить второй массив: бежим по массиву двумя индексами. Один - для нулевых элементов, второй - для ненулевых. встретив нулевой элемент - меняем его местами с первым ненулевым. Таким образом, все нулевые элементы соберутся в начале массива.

Comment: Еще модифицированным пузырьком можно, тащим ноль влево, пока не упремся в ноль или начало массива.

Comment: @aepot тоже сразу возникла такая мысль в голове :)

Answer (score 4):

Хоть вопрос не соответствует правилам портала, задача очень заинтересовала, и я решил написать решение-однострочник на LINQ:

```
var arr = new[] {1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 123, 19, 12, 0, 99, 0};
var resultArr = arr.OrderBy(i => i == 0 ? 1 : 2).ToArray();
```

Comment: Обалденный ответ! Он должен занять достойное место среди других однострочников на LINQ, типа вычисления простых чисел: Enumerable.Range (2, (int)Math.Sqrt(n)-1).All (i => n%i > 0)

Comment: коротко и медленно :) Время работы этого алгоритма будет nLogn, тогда как просто 2 указателя сделают дело за линейной время.

Comment: Точнее, простые числа в диапазоне ищем так: 
            int start = 5;
            int count = 100;
            var r = (ParallelEnumerable.Range(start, count).Where (n => Enumerable.Range (2, (int)Math.Sqrt(n)-1).All (i => n%i > 0))).ToList();

Comment: `Array.Sort(arr, (x, y) => x == 0 ? -1 : 0);` в кучу.

Comment: @tym32167 да, алгоритм не линейной сложности. Просто хотелось показать возможность управлять сортировкой с помощью `OrderBy`

Answer (score 2):

Можно сначала подсчитать сколько у вас нулевых элементов, а остальные просто запишите.
Скажем у вас массив из 50 элементов, и вы находите, что нулевых у вас 10, тогда просто пишете a[1]=0, a[2]=0, a[3]=0.... и до a[10]=0, потом записываете остальные, сравнивая с нулем, если равен нулю, то отбрасываете, если не равен записываете.

Comment: Точно, хорошая оптимизация! просто бежим по массиву, и за один проход все элементы с начала массива, котрые не равны нулю, переставляем на место нулевых элементов, которые ищем, начиная с конца массива...